# Conv2D produces weird output

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, image-processing, convolution

I'm trying to use a [Laplace Filter](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Laplacian%20is%20a%202,spatial%20derivative%20of%20an%20image.&text=The%20Laplacian%20is%20often%20applied,will%20be%20described%20together%20here.) via TensorFlow `tf.nn.conv2d` on my image. But the output is super weird and I don't have a clue what I did wrong.

I load my picture via:

```
file = tf.io.read_file("corgi.jpg")
uint_image = tf.io.decode_jpeg(file, 1)
image = tf.cast(uint_image,tf.float32)
kernel = tf.constant(np.array([[1, 1, 1],
                               [1, -8, 1],
                               [1, 1, 1]]), dtype=tf.float32)
convoluted_image = self.convoluteTest(image, kernel)
rs_convoluted_image = tf.reshape(convoluted_image,
                                 [tf.shape(image)[0] - tf.shape(kernel)[0] + 1,
                                  tf.shape(image)[1] - tf.shape(kernel)[0] + 1, 1])
casted_image = tf.cast(rs_convoluted_image, tf.uint8)
encoded = tf.io.encode_jpeg(casted_image)
tf.io.write_file("corgi-tensor-laplace.jpg", encoded)
```

But the image parameter cant be passed onto the tf.nn.conv2d function since image tensor requires to be a 4d tensor.

This function here reshapes and applies my laplace filter:

```
  def convoluteTest(image_tensor, kernel_tensor):
        shape = tf.shape(image_tensor)
        reshaped_image_tensor = tf.reshape(image_tensor, [1, shape[0].numpy(), shape[1].numpy(), 1])
        reshaped_kernel_tensor = tf.reshape(kernel_tensor,
                                            [tf.shape(kernel_tensor)[0].numpy(), tf.shape(kernel_tensor)[0].numpy(), 1,
                                             1])
        convoluted = tf.nn.conv2d(reshaped_image_tensor, reshaped_kernel_tensor, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')
        return convoluted
```

Original Picture:

[image]

Failed laplace:

[image]

Update:

Greyish output:

[image]

What did I do wrong? I can't wrap my head around this...

Comment: It is “convolved”, not “convoluted”. The process of applying a convolution is “to convolve”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is `casted_image = tf.cast(rs_convoluted_image, tf.uint8)` truncates data outside of [0, 255] to pure black or pure white (0 and 255).

I think you are missing a normalization step back to the `[0, 255]` range before casting to `utint8`.

Try

```
normalized_convolved = (rs_convoluted_image - tf.reduce_min(rs_convoluted_image) / (tf.reduce_max(rs_convoluted_image) - tf.reduce_min(rs_convoluted_image))
normalized_convolved = normalized_convolved * 255

casted_image = tf.cast(normalized_convolved, tf.uint8)
```

Comment: That was the right hint, but it now looks greyish, not black... But its a step forward...

Comment: @SebastianG. What's wrong with this image? What output did you expect? There are both white and black pixels. If you expect to find larger blobs, you should increase the kernel size

Comment: But does it have to be this greyish? I thought it would be more black

Comment: The data is what it is. See the example [here](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm#:%7E:text=The%20Laplacian%20is%20a%202,spatial%20derivative%20of%20an%20image.&text=The%20Laplacian%20is%20often%20applied,will%20be%20described%20together%20here.) .

Comment: @SebastianG.You can apply some color changes to map certain bit values to darker or lighter colors, for example [histogram equalization](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_histograms/py_histogram_equalization/py_histogram_equalization.html).

Comment: Normally, this filter is not used for visual purposes, and messing around with the way its output looks is rather useless. The normal use is [blob detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection) for which "greyness" doesn't matter, and for which even the conversion to `uint8` would interfere.

Comment: @SebastianG. I happen to have a [repo](https://github.com/noamzilo/BlobDetector) messing exactly with this. Feel free to check it out. Using cv2 and not tensorflow, but you will manage I am sure.

Comment: @SebastianG. I thought about how to "look" at this output: Remember the filter output is the second derivative. That is unsigned, meaning very negative or very positive values indicate a big change in the first derivative, while 0 means no change. Mapping some [negative, positive] range to [0, 255] will map large areas of 0 change in intensity [such as the water] to approximately 128, == gray, which is most of the picture, while the areas near the edges (not the edges themselves - this is the gradient itself) will be exclamated.

Comment: This explains it probably pretty well. I didnt know about normalization before so this was a massive help.